# fedora no installed groups file

Tags: fedora, yum

I just did a fresh install of Fedora Server 21.

I am trying to execute 
yum groupinstall gnome

and I get an error message 
There is no installed groups file.

How can I fix this?

More info:

```
[root@localhost run]# yum groups list
Loaded plugins: langpacks
There is no installed groups file.
Maybe run: yum groups mark convert (see man yum)
Warning: no environments/groups match:
[root@localhost run]#
```

Answer (score 1):

Installation of 'environment groups' fails due to conflicts between fedora-release packages

[link to this item - Bugzilla: #1160917](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F21_bugs#Installation_of_.27environment_groups.27_fails_due_to_conflicts_between_fedora-release_packages)

Due to some limitations in how Fedora's package group mechanism works and some changes made to support the introduction of "Flavors" in Fedora 21, you may often encounter conflicts when trying to install the 'environment groups' seen in yum grouplist after installing Fedora 21. If you install a Fedora Flavor - Workstation, Cloud, or Server - it is likely that attempting to install any other 'environment group' will fail. If you use a non-Flavor install - for instance, install from a desktop live image - it is likely that you will be able to successfully install other non-Flavor environment groups, but not the environment groups associated with each Flavor.

The most common case in which you're likely to encounter this is trying to add extra desktops to a Workstation or other desktop installation. If you install Workstation and then want to add any other desktop, or install another desktop and then want to add GNOME and decide to try and use the 'Workstation' group, you will likely run into this problem.

Fortunately there is a fairly simple workaround for this problem: use the command yum groupinstall (group) --exclude fedora-release*, e.g. yum groupinstall kde-desktop-environment --exclude fedora-release*. Note that you must use exactly yum groupinstall. yum group install will not work.

It may not be possible to resolve this fully for Fedora 21. The bug report contains the detailed explanation of the problem, and solutions for it will likely be discussed there, if you wish to keep up to date.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're missing the group file like error says...
What you need to do is re-create the repo pointing to the group file which is "comps.xml" file.

So:

createrepo -vg comps.xml /rpm-dir/

That will solve it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

yum groupinstall "gnome"

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/15815

Comment: Same error, :( 

There is no installed groups file.

Comment: it seems like the group "gnome" doesn't exists. Please try:
#yum  groups list 
Which will give you the available groups list.

Comment: [root@localhost run]# yum groups list

Loaded plugins: langpacks

There is no installed groups file.

Maybe run: yum groups mark convert (see man yum)
Warning: no environments/groups match:
[root@localhost run]#

Comment: $ sudo yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop Environment"

I think this is the correct name of the package.

Comment: same message. I've edited my original question with the output i get

Comment: I'm not quite sure in fedora server. I'm using fedora Desktop please give a chance to:

$yum groups mark install GNOME

Comment: i might just install fedora desktop then. this is my first experience with a server

Comment: You can download Fedora desktop with Gnome or Kde Desktop environment included.

Answer (score 0):

Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
There is no installed groups file.
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: fedora/19/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again

Solution
In your terminal, run the following commands.

```
#yum clean all
#yum grouplist hidden
#yum grouplist
```

Perform these commands as super user (i.e) root user.  Then see if your grouplist is in the list.  If so, then try to install again.

Comment: grouplist hidden command responds the same way "There is no installed groups file."

Comment: checking my fedora install

Comment: see my second answer on official Fedora 21 bugzilla report